# Apache spark WHERE clause not working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

I'm running Apache Spark 1.6.1 on a smaller yarn cluster.  I'm attempting to pull data in from a hive table, using a query like:

```
df = hiveCtx.sql("""
SELECT *
  FROM hive_database.gigantic_table
 WHERE loaddate = '20170502'
""")
```

However, the resulting dataframe is the entire table, no matter what value I give for loaddate.  The only odd thing I can think is that the hive table is partitioned by that loaddate column.

Hive alone appears to run this query correctly.  I've tried casting to ints, using `.filter()`, and various levels of quotation marks, but no luck on Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, filtering on a partition column is case-sensitive.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19292